# How to horizontally align with display:inline-block

Tags: html, css, display

Seems super simple but I am unable to horizontally center text in a parent element while using `display:inline-block` on the text. I need it to be `display:inline-block` because I want the border around the text I create to be the size of the text and **NOT** the parent.

Is there another way to make the border I give the text the width of the text and not the parent?

```css
    a.studio-nav {
      font-family: 'brandon-reg';
      font-weight: 900;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:7px 4px;
    }
    a.studio-nav:hover {
      border:2px solid white; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
      -moz-border-radius: 7px;
      border-radius: 7px;
      text-decoration: none;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <a href="/" class="studio-nav">
       text
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <a href="/" class="studio-nav">
       I want
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <a href="/" class="studio-nav">
       centered
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be as simple as this?

```
.row {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rczfnf6d/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has also a quick way of achieving this with an alignment class called ".text-center"

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-center"> <!-- class added-->
    <a href="/" class="studio-nav">
        text
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, your problem can be easily solved by setting position absolute to the anchor that contain the text you want to center

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
display: inline-table;
```

instead of

```
display: inline-block;
```